# How to make large "in" queries in C# for an indexed field in MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, query

In mssql, how can I run effectively this query:

```sql
select id from table where field in (gigantic list of ordered longs)
```

Table schema:

```
table:
{
  id primary key
  field long
} index findex (field)
```

I think this should be really fast (since it's basically just stepping through two ordered lists of longs).  Is there a way to continuously stream the IDs in?

I can do it from a console or using Linqpad/SSMS.

**Current (slow) Solution**: a console app which constructs many long queries, each with 3k fieldId arguments.  The limit on argument number is the problem; how to get around it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> select id from table where field in (gigantic list of ordered longs)

Queries with long `IN` lists are slow, as they are parsed and compiled each call.

Either pass the list as a JSON array:

```
select id from table where field in (select value from openjson(@values))
```

Or use a Table-Valued Parameter or bulk load a temp table with the values. Ensure there is an index or primary key. The [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql) method will likely be slower, but the upside is that it works with all client drivers.  TVP and Bulk Insert are not always available except in .NET and Java.

Answer (score 0):

The way a query like that is effectively evaluated is,
`WHERE field = x1 or field = x2 or field = x3.....`
which as your seeing can be very intensive. (Sometimes, the optimizer can use an index if available and will rewrite the query.)

What you can do to rewrite the query is to dump the fields you want into a temp table and then join between them. If you have a version of SQL Server that supports `STRING_SPLIT`, then you can use something like the below, that takes creates an sp with the long list as a variable, loads it to a temp table, and then joins to your original table.

```
CREATE PROC MyProc @LongList VARCHAR(MAX)  
AS

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #X 
CREATE TABLE #X (Field VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED) -- May Need To Change DataType

INSERT INTO #X (Field)
SELECT DISTINCT Value AS Field FROM string_split(@LongList,',')


SELECT 
T.*

FROM 
MyTable T
INNER JOIN #X X
ON T.Field = X.Field
```

Comment: Hi @BCM - the answer would be better if there was an example of the CTE the OP could look at?  Are your really saying you'd write out `with ....SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 20 UNION ....` and then do a join?

Comment: No, @MrR that was not my intention.  I realize my original answer was too vague, added an example to clarify.

Comment: A join will output duplicate rows if there is a duplicate value in the list.

Comment: Good point, @DavidBrowne-Microsoft. Added DISTINCT.